# c# Factory for concrete implementation of generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I have a Base class which is generic.
I have a concrete class which implements the base class.

How would I create a factory class/method for delivering different types of concrete classes?

Here an example:

```
public class ReceiverBase<T>
    where T : IInterpreter
{ ... }

public class SpecialReceiver : ReceiverBase<OwnInterpreter> { ... }

public class ReceiverFactory<T>
    where T : ReceiverBase<IInterpreter>, new()

    public T Create(string type) {
        switch(type) {
            default:
                return new SpecialReceiver();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that ReceiverBase seems not to be possible because the compiler only wants classes as Constraints, not interfaces.
And the second problem is that I cannot convert SpecialReceiver to T.

So is there a way to get this working?

=== EDIT: Added example according to first answer ===

```
public interface IInterpreter
{
}

public class OwnInterpreter : IInterpreter
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoSomething() { }
}



public abstract class ReceiverBase<T>
    where T : IInterpreter
{
    public T MyReceiver { get; set; }

    internal abstract void Start();
}

public class SpecialReceiver<T> : ReceiverBase<T>
    where T : IInterpreter, new()
{
    public void CheckSomething()
    {
        MyReceiver.DoSomething();
    }

    internal override void Start()
    {
        MyReceiver = new T();
    }
}

public class ReceiverFactory<T>
    where T : IInterpreter, new()
{
    public static ReceiverBase<T> Create(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            default:
                return new SpecialReceiver<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is: MyReceiver.DoSomething(); will not work.
Additionally I would have to call the factory like this: `ReceiverFactory<OwnInterpreter>.Create("");` I'd like to have it that way: `ReceiverFactory.Create("SpecialReceiver");`

Comment: Your first comment is not true at all. You can certainly have interfaces as constraints. What you may be experiencing, though, is that because you want to be able to `new` up instances of the type being constrained, you have to include the `new()` constraint, as you have.

Comment: Compiler says: The type IInterpreter must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter T. Compiler refers to this line: where T : ReceiverBase<IInterpreter>, new()

Comment: OK, I am corrected. You *can* have interfaces as constraints, but in this case you cannot because you are wanting to use `new()` and you have to guarantee that said constructor exists. Interfaces do not guarantee constructors.

Comment: Yes, you are right. the new() constraint was the problem for the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic method in your factory:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var own = ReceiverFactory.Create<OwnInterpreter>();
        var other = ReceiverFactory.Create<OtherInterpreter>();
        own.Start();
        other.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
interface IInterpreter
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class OwnInterpreter : IInterpreter
{
    public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("Own"); }
}

class OtherInterpreter : IInterpreter
{
    public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("Other"); }
}

abstract class ReceiverBase<T> where T: IInterpreter, new()
{
    public T Interpreter { get; set; }
    public ReceiverBase()
    {
        Interpreter = new T();  
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        Interpreter.DoSomething();
    }
}

class SpecialReceiver : ReceiverBase<OwnInterpreter> { }
class OtherReceiver : ReceiverBase<OtherInterpreter> { }

static class ReceiverFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> factories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    static ReceiverFactory()
    {
        RegisterFactory(() => new SpecialReceiver());
        RegisterFactory(() => new OtherReceiver());
    }
    public static void RegisterFactory<T>(Func<ReceiverBase<T>> factory) where T : IInterpreter, new()
    {
        factories.Add(typeof(T).FullName, factory);
    }
    public static ReceiverBase<T> Create<T>() where T : IInterpreter, new()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        return ((Func<ReceiverBase<T>>)factories[type.FullName]).Invoke();
    }
}
```

In fact, you do not need "new()" constraint here, since you use factories.

Comment: Thanks for the nice sample, but there is a general Problem here. I do not want to differentiate the Interpreters, but the Receiver classes. In my design problem I have different kind of sources for Information which is the same. In my case this is a location. (GPS, Cell, etc.) Every source provides Latitude and Longitude. I now want to have a factory which will provide the coordinates. I just want to call the factory with Create("GPS") or Create("Cell") or anything else which will provide this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code to:

```
    public class ReceiverBase<T> where T : IInterpreter
    {
    }

    public interface IInterpreter
    {
    }

    public class SpecialReceiver<T> : ReceiverBase<T>
        where T : IInterpreter
    {
    }

    public class OwnInterpreter : IInterpreter
    {
    }

    public class ReceiverFactory<T> where T : IInterpreter, new()
    {
        public ReceiverBase<T> Create(string type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                default:
                    return new SpecialReceiver<T>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason why you cannot just return `T` in your case is, that there is no implicit conversion between `SpecialReceiver` and `ReceiverBase<IInterpreter>`.

Comment: This would lead to two other problems:
I could not implement Code in SpecialReceiver which uses OwnInterpreter instancees.
I would need to call the factory with a concrete IInterpreter. in this case it would be OwnInterpreter. The factory should need only a string parameter which could be read from a config or somewhere else.

Comment: @DARKHalf which are? :)

Comment: Edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution which suits my needs.
I've added another interface IReciver which defines the properties and members I really need. The factory method returns IReceiver so I can omit all binding issues whith generics. Sometimes it is just that easy. :)

```
public interface IInterpreter { }

public interface IReceiver
{
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class OwnInterpreter : IInterpreter
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

public abstract class ReceiverBase<T> : IReceiver
    where T : IInterpreter, new()
{
    public T MyReceiver { get; set; }

    internal abstract void Start();

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool Enabled { get { return _isEnabled; } set { _isEnabled = value; OnEnable(value); } }

    internal abstract void OnEnable(bool isEnabled);

    protected ReceiverBase()
    {
        MyReceiver = new T();
    }
}

public class SpecialReceiver : ReceiverBase<OwnInterpreter>
{
    public void CheckSomething()
    {
        MyReceiver.DoSomething();
    }

    internal override void Start()
    {
        // just for testing puropses
        MyReceiver = new OwnInterpreter();
    }

    internal override void OnEnable(bool isEnabled)
    {
        MyReceiver = isEnabled ? new OwnInterpreter() : null;
    }
}

public class ReceiverFactory
{
    public static IReceiver Create(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            default:
                return new SpecialReceiver();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        ReceiverFactory.Create("");
    }
}
```